# Font disappearing on click in IE9 (Custom font, no Javascript on page)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

You can see the issue here:

http://referrals.users34.interdns.co.uk/

It works in all other browsers, it is using a custom font that is being generated by PHP (Base64 encoded). There is no javascript included on that page and the text seems to be just changing colour. However, not all the text with that custom font is disappearing, only the body text and the text above the table (Well, most of it). The navigation and grey text stays the same.

I am using the reset CSS:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I have tried Googling but couldn't find anything.

If anyone could help that would be great as I have absolutely no idea what is happening!

UPDATE: Happens in IE8 too.

Regards,
Connor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the culprit is `color: transparent` from `div:focus` in style.css (line 59)

when you click the text, IE is giving the focus to the div you click on which makes the text `transparent` per the style above.

you can remove that style or set the color explicitly for the elements that disappear.